# Is it possible to access a BDB from pure Java?

Tags: java, berkeley-db

I'm trying to access "cert8.db" mozilla file which is a BDB database. I know that there are bindings for languages, Java among them, but I'm trying to build a multiplatform app so I think that using JNI such as this one would be a problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had this in an answer but I deleted it cause it wasn't actually a useful answer. Oracle bdb java edition is actually pure java but it has a different on-disk format. More info in this faq entry: http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/faq/je_faq.html#2

Comment: That's right, I'm trying to access a native BDB (made by mozilla firefox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need full BDB package to read that file. Check out this class,

http://sam.nipl.net/code/mindterm/com/mindbright/bdb/DBHash.java

Comment: No. Read-only. If you are going to write, you should just convert it to the format used by Sleepycat Java library.

Comment: @J-16 SDIZ: Thanks for the updated link. I wish they'd used a standard license, with the Mindterm Public Source License I have no idea if I can use this code...