# Can I read BerkeleyDB (non-Java-edition) files from Java?

Tags: java, interop, berkeley-db

I need to read BerkeleyDB files from Java.

Oracle has an official Java Edition of BerkeleyDB, but it seems that this uses its own, incompatible binary file format.

What do I do?

Comment: Related question (limited to "pure Java"): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873581/is-it-possible-to-access-a-bdb-from-pure-java

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB#Editions), there are Java bindings for classic Berkeley DB, but they require use of JNI and a native library.  Here's a link to the Sleepycat [Berkeley DB - Java API](http://vickypark.com/doc/db4-devel-4.8.30/programmer_reference/java.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Berkeley DB can actually store data in 2 different formats, depending on whether you elect to use the SQL API or not. The SQL API is a recent addition, Berkeley DB has historically been a key/value database.

It is true that you need to build the native library and use JNI, but this is to be expected if you want to access files created by a native library. Fortunately, the build process is very simple.

If you are building under Windows, please refer to [the installation guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/installation/build_win.html).

For Linux or other *NIX, after you have untarred the file go to the build_unix directory and do one of the following:

- If you are using the (standard) key/value interface:

../dist/configure --enable-java --prefix=/usr/local/db

make install

- If you are using the SQL API:

../dist/configure --enable-sql --enable-jdbc --prefix=/usr/local/db

make install

(Obviously you can replace --prefix with the install location of your choice)

For more information see [the docs page](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/toc.htm).

Hope that helps, good luck with your project.