# How to access a hash type BDB by pure java

Tags: berkeley-db

I use bdb 4.7(not java edition) to create a hash type db, but I need to access it by pure java and I don't want to use JNI. 
I looked up some keywords in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873581/is-it-possible-to-access-a-bdb-from-pure-java)
But it can not solve my problem, I only need to read the bdb.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but for others who are seeking to use BDB in their java applications:

1) go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html

2) download and extract the java .tar.gz/.zip

3) add the .jar to your classpath

Hope this helps